# Как при помощи регулярных выражений найти строку, при этом чтобы она была без опознавательных слов(см. описание)

Tags: c#, регулярные-выражения

Я хочу найти слово, которое идет после слова Vovin. Для этого я пишу `"Vovin \w+"`. При исходном предложении *"Vovin velosiped ykrali"* я получу *"Vovin velosiped"*. А я хочу получить лишь velosiped. Как это можно сделать, пользуясь лишь регулярными выражениями из библиотеки C#?

Comment: `text.Split()[1]`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Используйте позитивный просмотр назад:

```
(?<=Vovin )\w+
```

Пример: [regex101.com](https://regex101.com/r/q7QXzn/1)

Answer (score 1):

https://regex101.com/r/ybl9g3/1

Вам нужно разбить регекс на группы с помощью скобок `()`, а чтобы не возвращались результаты для ненужной группы, её лучше заигнорить с помощью `?:`

```regex
(?:Vovin )(\w+)
```